# Range Dom SummerNote

Tags: jquery, html, dom, summernote

I have a problem with SummerNote (a WYSIWYG plugin for Bootstrap 3)

I tried to generate this:

```
<div class="video-container">
<iframe  src="http://blablabla"/>
</div>
```

With this jQuery code:

```
  $d = $("<div>").attr('class','video-container');
        $video = $('<iframe>')
          .attr('id','video-iframe')
          .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/blablabla')
          .attr('width', '640').attr('height', '360')
range.create().insertNode($('<div class="video-container">' + ($video[0]) + '</div>')[0]);
```

This gave the result:

> [object HTMLIFrameElement]

I don't understand why! Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're concatenating a string (`'<div class="video-container">'`) to a DOM object. This attempts to convert the DOM object to a string: like most Javascript objects, DOM objects do not convert to strings in any nice way and you get `[object HTMLIFrameElement]`.

You actually aren't terribly far off, but you should use jQuery's power a bit more. So rather than building an HTML string, do your manipulation with a jQuery selection.

```
var node = $('<div class="video-container" />'); //  create the div element
node.append($video); // add the video to the div

range.create().insertNode(node[0]); // add the node to the range
```